# React Native: How to pass props from a Button?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Any idea how I can pass props from a button to a Component accessed via reference?

The component: `<RBSheet ref={refRBSheet} >  </RBSheet>`

The caller Button: `<Button title="open" onPress={() => refRBSheet.current.open()} />`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `React.forward` ref for passing `ref prop to other components`.

For more information read this.

https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html